# React using Select Bootstrap populated from API. After submit form I want to unselect the previous selection

Tags: javascript, reactjs, bootstrap-5

After I submit the form I am setting the state to '' for the dropdown but still shows the selected item before I submitted the form. Can you help me to see what is the issue. Thanks

Find below my component code. I am able to reset the other fields but the Select one. Thanks

```
import React from 'react'
import {Form,Button} from 'react-bootstrap'
import { useState, useEffect, useContext } from 'react'
import { MemberContext } from '../contexts/MemberContext'
import { CategoryContext } from '../contexts/CategoryContext'
import { ContributionContext } from '../contexts/ContributionContext'
const Contribution = () => {

    const {sortedMembers} = useContext(MemberContext);
    const {sortedCategories} = useContext(CategoryContext);
    const {addContribution} = useContext(ContributionContext);
    const date1 = new Date();
    const defaultValue = date1.toLocaleDateString('en-CA');
    const [memberID, setMemberID] = useState([{'memberID':'','last_name':''}])
    const [date, setDate] = useState(defaultValue);
    const [notes, setNotes] = useState('');
    const [amount, setAmount] = useState(null);
    const [categoryID, setCategoryID] = useState('');

    const onSubmit = e => {
        e.preventDefault();
    
       
        addContribution(memberID,date,notes,amount,categoryID);
           
            setMemberID('');
            setNotes('');
            setAmount('');
            setCategoryID('');
            
        };
    return (
    <>
    <div className='container mt-5 ' >
    

    
<Form onSubmit={e => onSubmit(e)} >
<h1>Add Contribution</h1>
<br/>
    <br/>
<Form.Select aria-label="Default select example" className='form-control' onChange={(e) => setMemberID(e.target.value)}>
  <option >Choose MemberID</option>
 
  {
    sortedMembers.map(item =>(
        <option value={item.memberID } key={item.id} >{item.memberID} : {item.first_name} {item.last_name} </option>
    ) )
  }
  </Form.Select>
  <Form.Group className="form-control" >
    <Form.Control type="date" placeholder="Date *"  value={date} name="date" onChange={(e) => setDate(e.target.value)}/>
  </Form.Group>

  <Form.Group className="form-control" >
    <Form.Control type="text" placeholder="Notes *"  name='notes' value={notes} onChange={(e) => setNotes(e.target.value)} />
  </Form.Group>
  <Form.Group className="form-control" >
    <Form.Control type="number" placeholder='Amount *' name='amount' value={amount} onChange={(e) => setAmount(e.target.value)} min={0}/>
  </Form.Group>
  <Form.Select aria-label="Default select example" className='form-control'onChange={(e) => setCategoryID(e.target.value)}>
  <option >Choose Category</option>
  {
    sortedCategories.map(cat =>(
        <option value={cat.id} key={cat.id} >{cat.category}  </option>
    ) )
  }
  </Form.Select>
  
  

  <Button variant="primary" type="submit">
    Submit
  </Button>
</Form>
</div>
</>
```

)
}

export default Contribution

Answer (score 0):

In your code you are missing value property in the default option. Try changing `<option >Choose MemberID</option>` to `<option value="">Choose MemberID</option>`. Listing down all the changes that were made:

1. const [memberID, setMemberID] should not have object. Made it string.
2. The Select for member should pass memberID as value
3. Make the Select of category as controlled component too
4. All option tag should have value property

Check the correction in the code below

```
function Contribution() {
  const {sortedMembers} = useContext(MemberContext);
  const {sortedCategories} = useContext(CategoryContext);
  const {addContribution} = useContext(ContributionContext);
  const date1 = new Date();
  const defaultValue = date1.toLocaleDateString("en-CA");
  const [memberID, setMemberID] = useState(""); // make it string
  const [date, setDate] = useState(defaultValue);
  const [notes, setNotes] = useState("");
  const [amount, setAmount] = useState(null);
  const [categoryID, setCategoryID] = useState(""); //make it controlled
  const onSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    setMemberID("");
    setNotes("");
    setAmount("");
    setCategoryID("");
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <Form onSubmit={(e) => onSubmit(e)}>
        <h1>Add Contribution</h1>
        <br />
        <br />
        <Form.Select
          aria-label="Default select example"
          className="form-control"
          onChange={(e) => setMemberID(e.target.value)}
          value={memberID} // set value from useState
        >
          <option>Choose MemberID</option>

          {sortedMembers.map((item) => (
            <option value={item.memberID} key={item.id}>
              {item.memberID} : {item.first_name} {item.last_name}{" "}
            </option>
          ))}
        </Form.Select>
        <Form.Group className="form-control">
          <Form.Control
            type="date"
            placeholder="Date *"
            value={date}
            name="date"
            onChange={(e) => setDate(e.target.value)}
          />
        </Form.Group>

        <Form.Group className="form-control">
          <Form.Control
            type="text"
            placeholder="Notes *"
            name="notes"
            value={notes}
            onChange={(e) => setNotes(e.target.value)}
          />
        </Form.Group>
        <Form.Group className="form-control">
          <Form.Control
            type="number"
            placeholder="Amount *"
            name="amount"
            value={amount}
            onChange={(e) => setAmount(e.target.value)}
            min={0}
          />
        </Form.Group>
        {/* Make it controlled */}
        <Form.Select
          aria-label="Default select example"
          className="form-control"
          onChange={(e) => setCategoryID(e.target.value)}
          value={categoryID}
        >
          <option>Choose Category</option>
          {sortedCategories.map((cat) => (
            <option value={cat.id} key={cat.id}>
              {cat.category}{" "}
            </option>
          ))}
        </Form.Select>

        <Button variant="primary" type="submit">
          Submit
        </Button>
      </Form>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Hi, I added the value = '' for both memberID and categoryID but still showing the same issue. Thanks

Comment: I have corrected your code and added the comments. Please check the updated answer.